# how to compare the runtime input with text file

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting

I want to compare the input and text file word.

The text file has:

```
one 
two
three
```

Run time input assigned to a variable `var`:

```
read -p " enter the value : " var
while read first
do
  a=$first
  if [ "$a" == "$var" ] 
  then 
    echo  " $var is found "
  else
    echo " $var is not found "
    read -p " please enter correct value " $var
  fi
done < word.txt
```

I tried above code in my script, but it is not working.

Comment: What do you want the script to do? Currently, the user has to guess the data of the first line.  If they fail, they have to guess the data on the second line. If the succeed, the next line is read, and if that's not correct, the user has to guess the data on the third line.  Could you please describe what the script is _supposed_ to do?

Comment: That's is correct only. but this code is not working

Comment: it should check both text file word and user input . if it is not match, it will ask for correct input from user.

Comment: why $var in read command ?

 read -r " please enter correct value " $var

Comment: mistakenly i mentioned -r..it is changed now..if the $var value is wrong.. it will ask for new value.and again it will check the value

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what the flow should look like in your code, so I'll give two versions:

1. The user guesses until they correctly guess the current word in the file, then moves on to guess the second word, and so on.
2. The user guesses the current word, and moves on to the next regardless of whether the guess was correct or not.

The first variation:

```
exec 3<&1
n=0
while read word; do
    n=$(( n + 1 ))
    while true; do
        printf 'Word #%d\n' "$n"
        read -p 'guess the word: ' -u 3 guess
        if [ "$guess" = "$word" ]; then
            echo 'correct'
            break
        fi
        echo 'wrong, try again'
    done
done <words
exec 3<&-
```

We can't just `read` inside the loop as that would read from the *file*. Instead we read from filedescriptor 3, which is a copy of standard input made before the loop.  After the loop, this filedescriptor is closed.

The inner `while` loop iterates until a correct guess is made.

The second variation:

```
exec 3<&1
n=0
while read word; do
    n=$(( n + 1 ))
    printf 'Word #%d\n' "$n"
    read -p 'guess the word: ' -u 3 guess
    if [ "$guess" = "$word" ]; then
        echo 'correct'
    else
        echo 'wrong, next word...'
    fi
done <words
exec 3<&-
```

This is similar to the previous code, but without the inner `while` loop.